# Phylogenetics in R: different results when working on a tree compared to reading it in

Tags: r, tree, phylogeny

This question stems directly from a previous one I asked here:

[Phylogenetics in R: collapsing descendant tips of an internal node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38570074/phylogenetics-in-r-collapsing-descendant-tips-of-an-internal-node)

```
((((11:0.00201426,12:5e-08,(9:1e-08,10:1e-08,8:1e-08)40:0.00403036)41:0.00099978,7:5e-08)42:0.01717066,(3:0.00191517,(4:0.00196859,(5:1e-08,6:1e-08)71:0.00205168)70:0.00112995)69:0.01796015)43:0.042592645,((1:0.00136179,2:0.00267375)44:0.05586907,(((13:0.00093161,14:0.00532243)47:0.01252989,((15:1e-08,16:1e-08)49:0.00123243,(17:0.00272478,(18:0.00085725,19:0.00113572)51:0.01307761)50:0.00847373)48:0.01103656)46:0.00843782,((20:0.0020268,(21:0.00099593,22:1e-08)54:0.00099081)53:0.00297097,(23:0.00200672,(25:1e-08,(36:1e-08,37:1e-08,35:1e-08,34:1e-08,33:1e-08,32:1e-08,31:1e-08,30:1e-08,29:1e-08,28:0.00099682,27:1e-08,26:1e-08)58:0.00200056,24:1e-08)56:0.00100953)55:0.00210137)52:0.01233888)45:0.01906982)73:0.003562205)38;
```

I have created this tree from a gene tree in R, using the `midpoint` function to root it. Now I apply the following function to it:

```
drop_dupes <- function(tree,thres=1e-05){
  tips <- which(tree$edge[,2] %in% 1:Ntip(tree))
  toDrop <- tree$edge.length[tips] < thres
  newtree <- drop.tip(tree,tree$tip.label[toDrop])
  return(newtree)
}
```

Now my issue is that when I apply this function I do not get the tree I expected. The output when plotted looks like this:

[image]

However, if I write the tree out to a text file using `write.tree` and then read it in again as a Newick string, when I then apply the `drop_dupes` function above, I get a different tree, as shown in the below plot:

[image]

And this is what is confusing me. Why am I getting two different outputs when applying the same function to the very same tree, with the only difference being if it's read in or it's already a variable in R?

Edit: Here are some further details. The initial gene tree is as follows:

```
(B.weihenstephanensis.KBAB4.ffn:0.00136179,B.weihenstephanensisWSBC10204.ffn:0.00267375,(((B.cereus.NJW.ffn:0.00191517,(B.thuringiensis.HS181.ffn:0.00196859,(B.thuringiensis.Bt407.ffn:0.00000001,B.thuringiensis.chinensisCT43.ffn:0.00000001)0.879000:0.00205168)0.738000:0.00112995)0.969000:0.01796015,(B.cereus.FORC013.ffn:0.00000005,((B.thuringiensis.galleriaeHD29.ffn:0.00000001,(B.thuringiensis.kurstakiYBT1520.ffn:0.00000001,B.thuringiensis.YWC28.ffn:0.00000001)0.000000:0.00000001)0.971000:0.00403036,(B.cereus.ATCC14579.ffn:0.00201426,B.thuringiensis.tolworthi.ffn:0.00000005)0.000000:0.00000005)0.377000:0.00099978)0.969000:0.01717066)1.000000:0.04615485,(((B.cereus.FM1.ffn:0.00093161,B.cereus.FT9.ffn:0.00532243)0.990000:0.01252989,((B.cereus.AH187.ffn:0.00000001,B.cereus.NC7401.ffn:0.00000001)0.694000:0.00123243,(B.thuringiensis.finitimusYBT020.ffn:0.00272478,(B.cereus.ATCC10987.ffn:0.00085725,B.cereus.FRI35.ffn:0.00113572)0.994000:0.01307761)0.973000:0.00847373)0.972000:0.01103656)0.863000:0.00843782,((B.thuringiensis.9727.ffn:0.00202680,(B.cereus.03BB102.ffn:0.00099593,B.cereus.D17.ffn:0.00000001)0.741000:0.00099081)0.822000:0.00297097,(B.cereus.E33L.ffn:0.00200672,(B.cereus.S28.ffn:0.00000001,(B.thuringiensis.HD1011.ffn:0.00000001,(B.anthracis.Vollum1B.ffn:0.00000001,(B.anthracis.Turkey32.ffn:0.00000001,(B.anthracis.RA3.ffn:0.00099682,(B.anthracis.Pasteur.ffn:0.00000001,(B.anthracis.Larissa.ffn:0.00000001,(B.anthracis.Cvac02.ffn:0.00000001,(B.anthracis.CDC684.ffn:0.00000001,(B.anthracis.BFV.ffn:0.00000001,(B.anthracis.Ames.ffn:0.00000001,(B.anthracis.A16R.ffn:0.00000001,(B.anthracis.A0248.ffn:0.00000001,B.anthracis.A1144.ffn:0.00000001)0.000000:0.00000001)0.000000:0.00000001)0.000000:0.00000001)0.000000:0.00000001)0.000000:0.00000001)0.000000:0.00000001)0.000000:0.00000001)0.000000:0.00000001)0.000000:0.00000005)0.000000:0.00000005)0.956000:0.00200056)0.000000:0.00000006)0.805000:0.00100953)0.809000:0.00210137)0.957000:0.01233888)0.929000:0.01906982)1.000000:0.05586907);
```

I read it into R as tree1. I then use the following code:

```
#Function to label nodes and tips as sequential integers
sort.names <- function(tr){
  tr$node.label<-(length(tr$tip.label) + 1):(length(tr$tip.label)+ tr$Nnode)
  ##some of these are tips, some are nodes, need to treat differently
  tr$tip.label<-1:(length(tr$tip.label))
  return(tr)
}

#Function to check if tree is rooted, and if it is not to use midpoint #rooting
rootCheck <- function(tree){
  if(is.rooted(tree) == FALSE){
    rootedTree <- midpoint(tree)
  }
  return(rootedTree)
}

#The above mentioned function to remove duplicate tips
drop_dupes <- function(tree,thres=1e-05){
  tips <- which(tree$edge[,2] %in% 1:Ntip(tree))
  toDrop <- tree$edge.length[tips] < thres
  newtree <- drop.tip(tree,tree$tip.label[toDrop])
  return(newtree)
}

#Use functions on tree
a <- rootCheck(tree1)
b <- sort.names(a)
c <- di2multi(b, tol = 1e-05)
d <- drop_dupes(c)
```

Now at this point if I plot tree `d`, I will get the first plot above. However, if I write tree `c` to a text file, then read it back in and and then use the `drop_dupes` function on it, I will get the latter tree.

I have checked the newick file of tree `c` against the Newick tree at the top of the page and it is definitely the same.

Comment: Using your example tree, I get the second displayed tree. Check if you are not plotting another tree altogether.

Comment: Hi, I have checked this. Please see my edits for further information.

Comment: Now, I reproduce your problem. Let's see if I can solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `sort.names` function. It effectively rearranges the way the tree is written, and indexing then refers to other nodes than it should.

If you need the tip.labels numbered, why not label them separately?

```
tax.num <- data.frame(taxa = tree1$tip.label, 
    numbers = 1:(length(tree1$tip.label)))

a <- midpoint(drop_dupes(tree1))
a$tip.label <- tax.num$number[match(a$tip.label, tax.num$taxa)]

plot(a)
```

Also, `di2multi` seems to be redundant. It creates polytomies where the goal, as I understand it, is to discard tips with short branches.

Comment: Thanks, this resolves the issue perfectly. Just as a further point, as I need the nodes and tips labelled iteratively for later analysis, I would use a <- midpoint(drop_dupes(tree1)) first, and then create the data frame so that it only contains the remaining tips, and I can then add the node labels for a continuous sequence from tips to nodes.

Comment: @spiral01 As these are gene trees, I assume that you will have variable taxa sets between trees. Make sure to store the tax.num table for each gene tree to be able to check identity later on.